# size_t vs unsigned - What is the disadvantage of using unsigned

Tags: c++

I am totally confused about `std::size_t` and `unsigned`, actually preference of unsigned fundamental types. It seems that *std::size_t* is favored over all other unsigned types, regardless of where it is used. But in the following examples why should I favor std::size_t which is 8 bytes over a smaller unsigned fundamental type (I am on a 64 bit machine):

**Example #1:**

```
N = 100
for(unsigned char i=0; i<N; i++){}
```

why should I use `std::size_t` if I know that upper limit of the loop is 100 and `unsigned char` is good enough (it can hold until 255)

**Example #2:**

```
struct MyContainer
{
    unsigned m_Row;
    unsigned m_Col;
};
```

If I know `MyContainer` is meant for a maximum of 1000 rows and cols and `unsigned int` is plenty enough (even *unsigned short* can do the job), why should I use `std::size_t`. Using std::size_t will increase *MyContainer* size to 16 bytes whereas *unsigned* will keep it at 8 bytes.

Also in terms of performance would not it be better to use a proper choice of fundamental type rather than using std::size_t all the time?

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: `unsinged` is the same as `unsigned int`, while `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type (which may be different from `unsigned int`, it's not uncommon for it to be `unsigned long`). Some operators return a value of type `size_t`. And there's some semantic information in the use of `size_t` instead of plain `unsigned`, especially for readers of the code.

Comment: **If** you know limits at the compile-time, yes, you can do that (provided you write `static_assert`s for any such assumptions so the code doesn't break horribly later). However the difference time-wise isn't that large and you'll have to write a lot of `static_cast`s when interacting with standard headers (provided your compiler generates as many warnings as possible). "Saving" space on loop counter may well be meaningless if the loop is small enough (your `i` will in that case take "one register", probably `rcx`, either way).

Comment: Also, `size_t` is a proper fundamental type. It's implementation-defined and depends on the architecture you're compiling on.

Comment: Regarding the use of `unsigned char`, it's still a character-based type and can't be used as a generic integer for example with the stream operator `<<`. And there's almost never a use-case to be cheap and limit yourself to only 8 bits (or what `char` might be on your system). Not even on small embedded system. It also makes it harder to refactor the code if it need to be able to handle larger ranges in the future.

Comment: Look at what all the standard libraries return or use when reporting data structure sizes, it is always std::size_t, so it also makes sense to have index based values use the same type. e.g. `std::size m_Row;`.  Using std::size_t ensures you can access addressable memory (for large data), while `unsigned` does not and thus you are potentially limiting functionality where you don't have to. In the end `std::size_t` is usually an alias for a fundamental type (e.g. typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;`)

Comment: So from what I can understand is `std::size_t` should be the preferred unsigned type (like std::vector should be the preferred container in the first place) :)

Comment: @macroland Not really. `size_t` is preferred when you want to use an index that should be able to index any sized memory range on your target platform, as it's guaranteed to be able to do that no matter if the platform is 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit. If you're not using it as an arbitrary index, then you have to weigh in pros and cons of other types. If you know your container is limited to 1000 elements and *must* be able to handle 1000 elements, then an `uint16_t` or bigger is more correct. It depends on how pedantic about being able to compile across architectures.

Comment: *Also in terms of performance would not it be better to use a proper choice of fundamental type rather than using `std::size_t` all the time?* Abbreviated story. The performant fundamental type is a **word**, which will vary by platform: commonly some are 16-bit, some 32-bit, some 64-bit.  Historically, an **int** *used to* represent a **word**.  When PC platforms changed from 16-bit to 32-bit, there was a disruption when **int** became 32-bit.  With modern PCs, a **word** is 64-bit, but compilers kept **int** at 32-bit. And here we are, using `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are worrying about performance at the wrong level of abstraction. If you want to study to the impact of choosing `unsigned` and `size_t` on performance, then you need a real case, some code that you can compile and measure, where it actually would have impact. Your example #1 is certainly not such an example, because any self-respecting compiler would realize that `for(unsigned char i=0; i<N; i++){}` is not doing anything already on low levels of optimizations.

At the abstraction level you are actually looking at, code, you should care about expressiveness and semantics.

- `std::size` is the type to be used as size and index of container. It is guaranteed to be large enough to hold indices and sizes of container.
- `unsigned` is the type to be used when you want some unsigned integer, when the width guaranteed by the standard is sufficient, and you do not care about the exact width.

When you actually do care about the width, then you should use one of the fixed width integer types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer. (Note that then I am still not considering performance, but only the width of the type. When you receive a 8-byte unsigned integer over a wire then you better use the right type, rather than `unsigned`).

If you do worry about performance, you need to profile and measure. Performance improvments are typically achieved by considering the bigger picture, by choosing better algorithms. Either that, or you need to consider what your compiler does. Compilers are typically much better at spotting opportunities for optimizing than humans are and according to the as-if rule any tranformation that does not change the observable behavior is allowed. I already mentioned that your Example #1 can be optimized away completely. Though also in this case:

```
 for (unsigned i=0;i <2; ++i) {
        foo(i);
 }
```

A compiler can see that the loop is equivalent to

```
 foo(0);
 foo(1);
```

And that no `unsigned` has actually to be stored anywhere.

Comment: I would add that reducing sizes of some fields in a struct may lead to not reducing the size of the struct *at all* due to alignment. For example, if a struct has 2 `double`s and one array index, making this index 32-bit or 16-bit won't save any space; if it has 2 `double`s and two indices, reducing indices to 32 bit will save 25% size. Even in a case where these structs take 20% of total memory allocation, the change would reduce memory footprint by 5%. The only scenario when this seems worth considering is when the algorithm creates huge arrays of indices only.

Comment: @Abstraction If you care about width, you would choose neither `unsigned` nor `size_t` ;) though, I suppose you are right. good point

Comment: I am actually trying to understand why `std::size_t` is mostly preferred even when a smaller data type can do the same job (as in example #1). I am aware that performance gain in example #1 will be none. However, considering example #2, please see "C++ High Performance ..." book Chapter 4. Reducing the class size can increase the performance considerably. Therefore, if I can use `unsigned` or `unsigned short` why should I prefer `std::size_t`.

Comment: @macroland as I wrote in the answer, the reason is that `size_t` is guaranteed to be wide enough to represent sizes and indices of containers and arrays. `unsigned` does not give that guarantee

Comment: @macroland I dont have the book available. I find it weird that it talks about `unsigned` vs `size_t` when width of the types is the topic. As I wrote in the answer, when you care about witdh of the type you would use fixed size integer types, and you would not use `unsigned` or `size_t`. Maybe the book predates c++11?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: The book does not compare `unsigned` and `size_t` in that particular chapter. It talks about how declaration order of the variables can impact the class size and how a reduced class size can impact the performance. Goes further to give actual examples using STL.

Comment: @Macroland ok then it is your misunderstanding. You wouldnt choose between `unsigned` or `size_t` when you want to minimize the size of a struct, but you would choose the smallest fixed size integer type that fits your needs.

Comment: @macroland the c++ standard only specifies minimum width of `unsigned`, it can be that or it can be more. If you write code where you care about the width of the type, you dont use `unsigned` (and usually also not `size_t`, unless the requirement is to be wide enough to hold any size and index of arrays/container)

Comment: OK. I will consider using `std::uint8_t`, `std::uint16_t` ... where I am sure of the range as these are guaranteed by standard across different platforms, otherwise stick to `std::size_t` .